# how to pass a parameter in onKeyDown action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', handle);
  function handle(e) {
   let value = document.getElementById("t11").value 
    if(e.code == "Space"){
      if(value =="n")value="t"
      else if(value == "t")value="P"
      else if(value == "P")value="S"
      else if(value =="S")value="n"
      else value ="n"
      document.getElementById("t11").value = value
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.3.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<label>Focus the input first (e.g. by clicking in it), then try pressing Space.</label>
<input type="text" id="t11"   className="attendanceInput"  readonly/>
</body>
</html>
```

I have an input which, by pressing the spacebar, changes the values :

```
<input type="text" id="11"  onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown.bind()} className="attendanceInput" readOnly/>
```

```
 handleKeyDown(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
      let value = e.value
      if(value =="n")e.value ="t"
      else if(value == "t")e.value="P"
      else if(value == "P")e.value="S"
      else if(value =="S")e.value="n"
      else e.value ="n"
      document.getElementById("11").value=e.value
    }
  }
```

and I need to take the input id to update the value and other actions. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to pass the input id in the parameter of the handleKeyDown function is that it?

Comment: You need to keep track of your desired input within local component's state and simply have assigned property `value` of your input to that state variable, e.g. `<input ... value={this.state.myString} ...>`

Comment: If you want the 'input' element, you can use 'this' inside the function to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of approaching this issue would be to call `e.currentTarget.id` within the `handleKeyDown` method, which will return the `id` of the input element.

However, if you wish to update the value of the `input` element, you will need to maintain a local state within your component, and subsequently update the state by binding the state update the `onChange` event.

```
<input value={input1}  onChange={(e) => this.handleInput(e)} className="attendanceInput" />
```

Comment: thank you) e.currentTarget.id what I need, I will use it to mark attendance, how would you implement such a component? P.s I'm a beginner in rectjs

Comment: @RavshanGafurov I would recommend you to maintain it via the component's state, as mentioned in my second part in my solution. Reason being, it is much more intuitive to toggle it via the state.

Comment: I just want to do it but through id. I have a different number of inputs each time. I'm going to store their value in the state and send it to the server in the submit